# Are there alternative words or phrases to "net worth" that don't imply it determines a person's value?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, terminology

I've never liked the term "net worth"; it seems to imply that a wealthier person is more valuable or important. Are there alternative words or phrases which do not have this problem?

> Bill Gates's [word or phrase] is $114 billion.

Comment: _Fortune_, perhaps?

Comment: The core problem is attributing the net worth of Gates the human as a stand in for Gates's assets. His net worth is actually his assets' & liabilities' net worth.

Comment: The problem with using another term is that the reader will wonder what you’re trying to say if you avoid the commonly used and understood term.

Comment: Related: [How is the worth of a person an amount of money?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/521314).

Answer (score 1):

Simplicity is best.

> Bill Gates has $114B.

Comment: While it does indeed make sense, your answer is a comment at best. Sans any supporting details, which authenticate an answer, it'd best be relegated to a comment.

Comment: What sort of details are you expecting?

Comment: I mean fleshing out your answer, Sir.

Comment: What extra information would you like?

Comment: I don't think this answer needs anything else. It's short, but it's still a good answer; there's not really anything else to add.

Answer (score 1):

You can use FINANCIAL WORTH

> Definition & Legal Meaning ([thelawdictionary](https://thelawdictionary.org/financial-worth/))
>
> This term applies to the net value of a person’s assets and property
> after his liabilities and debts have been taken away.

There is no defined term for FINANCIAL WORTH before liabilities and debts have been taken away.

Answer (score 0):

When we weigh assets against liabilities, the result is a ["balance"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/balance):

> 4a accounting : an amount in excess especially on the credit side of an account

You could therefore write:

> The net balance of Bill Gates's accounts is $114 billion.<sup>1</sup>

If it was clear that you were talking about Gates's financial portfolio, then the term could work in your sentence with no modifications:

> Bill Gates's net balance is $114 billion.

---

<sup>1</sup>I've retained the word "net" from your question even though it's probably redundant here.

Comment: I don't think this is commonly used of people. It's also often used for corporate income/expenditure or (with countries) balance of payments.

Comment: @StuartF I agree; that's why I recommend saying "of Bill Gates's accounts". Accounts can have balances.